# Quantitative risk management for energy markets

Tags: risk-management, quantitative, risk-models, financial-markets

I'm currently preparing an exam about energy markets. The knowledge of notions of quantitative risk management accounts for the 50% of the total exam. During my university education, though, I didn't follow a specific risk management course. 
What are the most important topics that I should revise? Could you suggest me a good online book where I can easily revise the basics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book ["Managing Energy Risk An Integrated View on Power and Other Energy Markets"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Managing+Energy+Risk%3A+An+Integrated+View+on+Power+and+Other+Energy+Markets%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118618639) by Burger et al. (2014) may be very helpful as it not only introduces the relevant notions, but does so directly from an energy perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment site [risk.net](https://www.risk.net/). You can find a lot of artciles and books on risk management there.

You can also try to find some book on risk management here: [bookboon.com](https://bookboon.com). The site offer many books from many fields, incuding finance, management and business for free (some ads are added to PDF, however).